# Windows 7 ping general failure

Tags: windows, networking, ping

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of ping command. Trying to experiment on a windows 7 PC. 
On the command prompt, I issued the following command:

```
ping <some hostname> -l 4096
```

The output I get is

```
Pinging <some hostname> [xx.xx.xxx.xx] with 4096 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.

Ping statistics for xx.xx.xxx.xx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

However, `ping <same hostname> -l 32` works just fine.

So my question is why is the server behaving differently for different packet sizes? Is it related to thwart? Or is that my local ping program is configured by default in such a way so as to not sent *bigger* packets?

Note that -l flag lets you specify the ping req's buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

Your ping packet is probably larger than the local media's MTU, and it's on a network type where fragmentation isn't allowed.  Ethernet IPv6 would be one such configuration.